# Views that inherit a table and syntax in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I am getting a syntax error but don't understand what is wrong.

I am using a reference [here](http://www.cybertec.at/inheritance-one-more-reason-to-love-postgresql/).

This is my sql-snippet:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW stipa_test.stipa_view
AS 
  (
    SELECT *
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
  )
INHERITS (stipa_test.stipa_type_proj);
```

I hope you get the idea, everything but inheritance works. So how could it look like? both the subquery view and the type_proj table

Answer (score 1):

[Views cannot inherit.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html)

[Only tables can.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html)

Aside: the query for `CREATE VIEW` does not need parentheses. And your whole `SELECT` is needlessly convoluted and buggy. Untangled and without the invalid `INHERITS` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW stipa_test.stipa_view AS 
SELECT aar.gid AS aar_gid, aar.geom AS aar_geom 
     , aar_korr.gid AS aar_korr_gid, aar_korr.geom AS aar_korr_geom 
FROM   stipa_test.stipa_type_aar  aar
JOIN   stipa_test.stipa_type_aar_korr aar_korr
                   ON ST_Within(aar.geom, ST_Buffer(aar_korr.geom, 3))
-- and 'aar_korr.dato' > 'dato.aar'  -- nonsense, always FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstanding about the term inheritance as it applies in SQL.

You have a table structure with column

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a int, b int, c int );
```

If you want a view that *inherits* from that table, you need to select from it explicitly. "Inherits" means something [very specific in SQL parlance](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html) and it's not applicable to views. "Inheritance" in OOP refers to a method of eliminating redundancy by using data from a parent as a template. In SQL, "inheritance" is an implementation detail that should typically be avoided -- though sometimes useful in things like sharding.

So for instance, you can add a column `d` to table `foo` in a view by appending it on the query.

```
CREATE VIEW bar
AS
  SELECT foo.*, 'myval' AS d
  FROM foo;
```

You can read more about SQL-Inheritance in my answer ot [*Using table inheritance instead of mapping tables*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/157425/2639).